# Pass parameter of Sharepoint choice filter in URL to detail report

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a Sharepoint page with 2 SSRS graphs. The graphs have 2 parameters for division and company. I have included a Choice Filter at the top of my page so when you click the filter you can select from a list of divisions. When one is selected, both graphs change to show only that division data.

The graphs also link to detail reports and I am passing the parameter values through a URL to get to the detail reports. Below is my URL:

```
https://spotlight.sunlandasphalt.com/_vti_bin/reportserver?https://spotlight.sunlandasphalt.com/Reports/Dashboards/Days%20To%20Collect%20Detail%20Report.rdl&DaysToCollectDivision=[Days To Collect].[Division].[All]&DaysToCollectCompany=[Days To Collect].[Company].%26[1]
```

This is working fine but I want to know if there is a way to have whatever is selected in the Choice Filter be passed to the detail report? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the choice filter part of the SSRS report or in the SharePoint page?

Comment: The choice filter is in the SharePoint page. The company didn't really care at the moment about filtering it but if you have any ideas I could try it and see if they like it better.